# How to set limit for array size in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Would you be kind to tell me is there any way to set limitation on array size while creating Mongoose schema. For example

```
 var peopleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
   /* here I want to have limit: no more than 10 friends.
    Is it possible to define in schema?*/
    friends: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'peopleModel'
    }]
})
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible in Mongoose. What is the purpose of the size limit? You can often enforce size limits with your update operations using `$push` and [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/).

Comment: @wdberkeley hi! of course I can check it outside of base. But I simply think that much effective to do this while I make push to base, otherwise I have to in the first step ask my base if it possible to add one more document and only after it make push.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

With a small tweak to your schema setup you can add a [validate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) option:

```
var peopleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: true
  },
  friends: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'peopleModel'
    }],
    validate: [arrayLimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 10']
  }
});

function arrayLimit(val) {
  return val.length <= 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jason Cust , it's exactly what I need

Comment: Will this work even if i want only particular length such as 4?

Comment: @kannan Just noticed your question, so I apologize for the delay. Yes it would. All you would need to do is change the comparison to an equality check: `val.length === 4`.

Comment: This is great, does anyone know if there is a way to do it where it would keep the most 10 and drop the 11th with each save?

Comment: @McB, there are a few ways of doing it (e.g. via a property setter or a pre-validate middleware) which depend on how you expect to automatically handle modifying data.

Comment: Not working on my side

Comment: This does not work anymore

Answer (score 11):

starting from mongo 3.6 you can add validation for a collection at server end, each document inserted/updated will be validated against the validator [$jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema), only the valid gets inserted, validation error will be for invalid documents

```
db.createCollection("people", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: ["string"],
               description: "must be a string"
            },
            friends: {
               bsonType: ["array"],
               items : { bsonType: ["string"] },
               minItems: 0,
               maxItems: 10,
               description: "must be a array of string and max is 10"
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

collection

```
> db.people.find()
```

valid document

```
> db.people.insert({name: 'abc' , friends : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

invalid document

```
> db.people.insert({name: 'def' , friends : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10', '11']})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

find

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a9779b60546616d5377ec1c"), "name" : "abc", "friends" : [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ] }
>
```

Comment: This is so interesting, but... I wonder if this is the right way to do. Eg. reminds me of some insurance company which business logic was(still is?) kept in Oracle's embedded procedures... It was very cumbersome to change it and perform quality assurance over it. Another thing which hits me is that when there is server with use cases that do the business logic there is plenty of validation. First you have to validate payloads from user land (eg UI), second you have to validate domain business rules. So what would be the purpose of using validation in side DB then?

Answer (score 8):

You can use $slice modifier at the time you push new friend id into your array 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice

```
$push: {
  friends: {
   $each: [id],
   $slice: -10
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution to keep last ten elements, yet I think it's not restricting the schema though. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

This is my schema and array limit on assignedToId via an external function.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const taskSchema = new Schema({
  parentTask: {
    trim: true,
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "task",
  },
  assignedToId: [{
    trim: true,
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Employees",
  }],
  createdBy: {
    trim: true,
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Employees",
    required: [true, "User ID is required"]
  },
  createdByName: {
    trim: true,
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Creater name is required"]
  },
},
  {
    timestamps: true
  });

// Validations for assignedTo employees' size
taskSchema.path('assignedToId').validate(function (value) {
  console.log(value.length)
  if (value.length > 10) {
    throw new Error("Assigned person's size can't be greater than 10!");
  }
});

const Tasks = mongoose.model("Tasks", taskSchema);

module.exports = Tasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i know how to achieve the solution you're looking for is to create a closure function that passes in a number as an argument so that you can reuse the function on multiple arrays.

it would look like this

```
 var peopleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
   /* here I want to have limit: no more than 10 friends.
    Is it possible to define in schema?*/
    friends: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'peopleModel',
        validate: [limitArray(10), 'Cannot have more than ten 
        friends']
    }
})

function limitArray(limit){
    return function(value){
        return value.length <= limit;
    }
}
```

In my own project i have this function in its own file as an export so that i can import it into any number of schemas i need it on.