# Mongoose slice array, in populated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following `mongoose` schemas:

The main one is `userSchema` which contains an array of friends,
`friendSchema`. Each `friendSchema` is an object that contains an array of `messageSchema`. The `messageSchema` is the deepest object, containing the body of the message.

```
var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    body: String
});

var conversationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    messages: [messageSchema]
});

var friendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  conversation: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Conversation',
  },
}, { _id : false });


var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    friends: [friendSchema]
});
```

When retrieving specific user's friend, I populate its friends profiles, and if a conversation exist, I populate the conversation too.
How can I slice `conversations.messages` array, which resides in the population of the `conversation`object ? I don't want to return the whole messages.

```
  var userId = req.userid;
  var populateQuery = [{ path:'friends.user', 
                         select: queries.overviewConversationFields },
                       { path:'friends.conversation' }];

  User
  .find({ _id: userId }, { friends: 1 })
  .populate(populateQuery)
  .exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) { next(err); }
    console.log(result);
  }
```

**EDIT(1)** : I tried

```
  .slice('friends.conversation.messages', -3)
```

**EDIT(2)** : I tried in populate query

```
  { path:'friends.conversation', options: { 'friends.conversation.messages': { $slice: -2 } }
```

**EDIT(3)** : For now, I can achieve what I want, slicing the array after the query is executed. This isn't optimized at all.

Comment: Limit size of the array as in? Can you please be more specific.

Comment: As the array contains the whole conversation between the two users, I would like to be able to retrieve only the 25 last messages for example :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema

Comment: Check the first answer there. Should do the trick. Cheers

Comment: I don't think so. This validate option is for insertion purposes.

Comment: *set limitation on array size while creating Mongoose schema*

Comment: Did you try it mate? If it doesn't work we'll have to make a workaround for the same.

Comment: I didn't tried because this solution aims to prevent inserting more elements to the array, than specified in the validate function, not slicing the array when returning it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112427/discussion-between-gandalf-the-white-and-maltesefalcon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little workaround that works.
I didn't found how to `$slice` an array that resides in a populated field.

**However**, the `$slice` operator works perfecly on any `array`, as long as its parent document has'nt been populated.

**1)** I decided to update the `conversationSchema` by adding an array containing both user's Id involved in the conversation :

```
var conversationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users: [type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    messages: [messageSchema]
});
```

**2)** Then, I can easily find every conversation my user participates to.
As I said, I can properly slice the `messages` array, because nothing has to be populated.

```
Conversation.find({ users: userId }, 
                  { 'messages': { $slice: -1 }}, function(err, conversation) {
});
```

**3)** Finally all I have to do, is to query all friends and conversations separately, and put back everything together, with a simple loop and a `_find`.
That would do *more or less* the same procedure of a Mongo `population`

Using `async.parallel` for more efficiency :

```
 async.parallel({
      friends: function(done){
        User
          .find({ _id: userId }, { friends: 1 })
          .populate(populateQuery)
          .exec(function(err, result){
          if (err) { return done(err);}
          done(null, result[0].friends);
        });
      },
      conversations: function(done){
        Conversation.find({ users: userId }, { 'messages': { $slice: -1 }}, function(err, conversation) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          done(null, conversation)
        });
      }}, function(err, results) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }

          var friends = results.friends;
          var conversations = results.conversations;

          for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
            if (friends[i].conversation) {
              friends[i].conversation = _.find(conversations, function(conv){ 
                return conv._id.equals(new ObjectId(friends[i].conversation));
              });
            }
          }

      });
      // Friends contains now every conversation, with the last sent message.
```