# Remove last item(s) from array after push new

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For example i have some Collection with array of `actions`

e.g. i push item(s) to actions array, so can i somehow set limit of element's in array(in schema) or delete items out of lenth in one query(i push new actions to the start)

don't need validate and throw error, just delete items out of range

```
$push: {
  action: {
    $each: [_newAction],
    $position: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema

Comment: will above link help

Comment: i don't want to validate array, just cut the last items in 1 query