# How to limit maximum reference of the parental node in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, tree

I have to create a tree structure with `mongodb` and of the four methods suggested by the official doc (parental reference, child reference, array of ancestors, materialized paths, nested sets) I have decided to use `array of ancestors` because the tier of the tree will be quite deep potentially thousands of levels or more. So I thought the penalty in storage could be compensated by faster speed due to less query being required when looking for all the parents of a node.

The problem is that the tree has to be strictly binary. So for example node 1 will only have node 2 and node 3 as its children and no more. Unfortunately only way I can think of doing this right now is to find all the documents that reference the specific parent that I would like to reference in the next document and if the count does not exceed 2, I insert the document referencing the target parent.

Obviously the problem is the multithreaded nature of mongodb and even if it wasn't, the request to look up the count that references the target parent could come in between the scanning and insertion of the previous document which would cause a third insertion if there were one document already referencing the target parent.

Is there a way I can make sure that only two nodes can reference a parent node in multithreaded environment of both mongodb and the server?

Comment: What about storing all parent nodes in an array(before inserting), then with mongoose validate ([array validation exp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema)) you could check before inserting that the new node occurrence <= 1  ?

Comment: @LefiTarik then it would throw error right? and if it does I just continue into searching available node. However I was thinking more like a niche transaction which would sequentially be executed. I'm probably better off with SQL in using this but I was just wondering if there's a workaround on Mongo as well because surely someone must have done it before

Comment: when you're going to use ***the mongoose custom validation***, the insertion will throw an error with your customised validation message, so it will ensure what you're looking for, but mongodb doesn't give this behavior natively especially that in your tree type choice there is no use of the ***children*** field that could simplify a lot the validation! so with this solution you have to store all used nodes inside an array to be checked (validate) whith every insertion and could be in a node with id='config' ?

Comment: @LefiTarik that's actually not a completely bad idea but I prefer not to store an array especially in cases like these when I have no idea how big the array is going to be but sure it could be a way to go with if I don't have any other choice I think

Comment: Yes, but consider that storing an array wouldn't make any problem even if it's huge, and i see this is the only way to handle the binary aspect of the tree, else you could implement the children field(***child reference***) that 'll simplify the implementation as said Saravana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using mongo version 3.6, you can enable schema validation using `$jsonSchema` at the server side

each document we update/insert will be validated against the validation schema, it the validation fails an error will be thrown and no modification will be made on the document

sample `node` collection schema

```
{
   _id : string,
   parent : [string, null],
   children : string[2]
}
```

validation schema

```
db.createCollection("node", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "_id" ],
         properties: {
            parent: {
               bsonType: ["string", "null"],
               description: "must be a string"
            },
            children: {
               bsonType: ["array"],
               items : { bsonType: ["string"] },
               minItems: 0,
               maxItems: 2,
               description: "must be a array of string and max is 2"
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

inserts [with valid documents]

```
> db.node.insert( { _id: "Books", children: [ "Programming" ], parent: null } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.node.insert( { _id: "Programming", children: [ "Databases", "Languages" ], parent: "Books" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.node.insert( { _id: "Languages", children: [ ], parent: "Programming" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.node.insert( { _id: "Databases", children: [ "MongoDB", "dbm" ], parent: "Programming" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.node.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", children: [ ], parent: "Databases" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.node.insert( { _id: "dbm", children: [ ], parent: "Databases" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
```

find

```
> db.node.find()
{ "_id" : "Books", "children" : [ "Programming" ], "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : "Programming", "children" : [ "Databases", "Languages" ], "parent" : "Books" }
{ "_id" : "Languages", "children" : [ ], "parent" : "Programming" }
{ "_id" : "Databases", "children" : [ "MongoDB", "dbm" ], "parent" : "Programming" }
{ "_id" : "MongoDB", "children" : [ ], "parent" : "Databases" }
{ "_id" : "dbm", "children" : [ ], "parent" : "Databases" }
```

insert with invalid document [children size > 2]

```
> db.node.insert({_id : "1", children : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], parent : "p1"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
>
```

insert failed with a validation error

update - trying to add 3rd child for _id Databases, failed with validation error

```
> db.node.updateOne( { _id: "Databases"}, {$push : {children: [ "Oracle" ]}} )
2018-02-25T21:00:08.087+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] WriteError: Document failed validation :
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 121,
    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "_id" : "Databases"
        },
        "u" : {
            "$push" : {
                "children" : [
                    "Oracle"
                ]
            }
        },
        "multi" : false,
        "upsert" : false
    }
})
WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:466:48
Bulk/mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:846:49
Bulk/executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:910:13
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1154:21
DBCollection.prototype.updateOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:572:17
@(shell):1:1
>
```

please refer [schema-validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) & [jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema) for more options, adding validation to existing collection and handling validation failures

Comment: the problem is with ***Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors*** you don't use the children field.

Comment: Yes, but with this model we can add limit restriction  and  do `$graphLookup` to get all parents