# How to validate array length when using $push?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to limit the amount of elements a user can add to an array field on one of my schemas. I'm currently adding the elements to the array using `Schema.findOneAndUpdate();` with the `$push` operator.

The first thing I tried was the solution given by another answer here on StackOverflow, namely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29418656/6502807
This solution adds a validate function to the fields in the schema definition. By setting `runValidators` to true, I did get the function to run with `Schema.findOneAndUpdate()`. It was at that moment, however, that I stumbled upon the next problem. At the end of the Validation chapter in the Mongoose docs it says:

> Also, $push, $addToSet, $pull, and $pullAll validation does not run any validation on the array itself, only individual elements of the array.

So attempting to check for array length did not work when using `$pull`. It simply supplied the validation function with an empty array every time, regardless of its actual contents in the database.

Next thing I tried was to use a `pre` hook. This was without any success as well. For some reason it did not execute the hook, even with `runValidators` set to true. This is how I defined said hook:

```
Settings.pre('update', async function (next) {
    if (this.messages.length > MAX_MESSAGES) {
        throw new Error('Too many messages');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** The reason the function did not fire was because I was using `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `update` this is fixed and the function now runs. The solution code above, however, does not work.

The schema with the array looks like this:

```
const Settings = new mongoose.Schema({
    // A lot more fields not relevant to this question
    messages: {
        type: [{
            type: String
        }]
    }
});
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that these update statements are used in conjunction with other options. I need the update statement to behave like an update or insert so my complete set of options looks like this:

```
{
    runValidators: true,
    setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
    upsert: true,
    new: true
}
```

When executing queries with the pre hook set like this, the array limit can be exceeded without any validation error being thrown.

At this point I'm wondering if there is any sensible way to do a max length check like this without having to do it myself outside of mongoose's abstraction layer.

I am using Mongoose 5.2.6 running on node v9.11.1 with MongoDB 4.0.0.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is your mongodb and mongoose version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've updated my question with some version information.

Comment: You can use `$expr` as well `db.collection.update(
 { $expr: { $gt: [{"$size": "$messages" }, MAX_MESSAGES] }},
 { update_statement }
)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet That's an interesting approach as well. It wouldn't throw validation errors but I suppose you could easily check if any document got updated after the `findOneAndUpdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the `pre update` hook. The thing is that that hook would not by default `give` you the update being mage so you can verify etc. You have to `take it` via `this.getUpdate()`:

```
Settings.pre('update', async function (next) {
    var preUpdate = this.getUpdate()
    // now inside of the preUpdate you would have your update being made and should have the array in there on which you can check the length
});
```

To give you an idea in my test schema I had to do something like this on an update with a **$set**:

```
this.getUpdate().$set.books.length   // gave me 2 which was correct etc
```

I also had no issues running and hitting the `update` hook at all. It looks super simple out of the mongoose docs:

```
AuthorSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  console.log('UPDATE hook fired!')
  console.log(this.getUpdate())
  next();
});
```

Comment: I've managed to get the function to fire, however getUpdate() just gets me the update part of my query, not the full array. `$set` is undefined on the object `getUpdate()` gave me. The reason the pre hook wouldn't fire was because I was using `findOneAndUpdate()`, that's fixed now.

Comment: Yes I did a `$set` update that is why it was not undefined for me. I am confused however ... You now have the updated part of the array and have the id of the model for which you can easily get the record and the current array ... what is the issue?

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should make another query in this pre hook to then fetch the current array count?

Comment: Sure and now you would have the incoming change and the current array length.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are using latest version from mongodb and mongoose then you can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator

```
const udpate = await db.collection.update(
  { $expr: { $gt: [{"$size": "$messages" }, MAX_MESSAGES] }},
  { update }
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this particular example never be able to throw an error? If the messages array exceeds the limit, the query wouldn't find anything and therefore not update, right?

Comment: @SjoerdDal precisely

Comment: Well, I do quite like this approach as it doesn't require making an additional query, albeit not as clean by not having validation inside of a hook.