# How to set an array of object ids to be 'required' in a mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, mongoose-schema

I have a schema that I want to save an array of object ids. I want to set the mongoose validation so that the array is never empty. It should have at least one object id.Here is what I have so far:

```
arrayOfObjectIds:[{ 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true 
  }],
```

Will it work as I desire or do I need to set up a validation function that checks the document before it is saved and ensures that the length of the array is greater than 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema

Comment: `required: true` should do validation for at least saving a document, since you don't have an upper limit or range for `length` you shouldn't need `validator` function.