# Set maximum items in array, and override when full

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I building a function which will store log-files, (in a string format) from a streaming device I use.

The device is sending 1 log-file pr minute, and stores it in an Array.

What I want to do is to store ONLY the logs from the last three days so I don't overload my DB with deprecated data.

1. Is there a way in Node.js // mongoose by which I can set a maximum of items in my Array (ex of 4320 items)?
2. And when the array is full, then the oldest ones shall be removed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set limit for array size in Mongoose schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema)

Comment: You can try running cron job which  removes previous data from database.

Comment: @ibrahimijc, Off cause I could do that - With the marker of xx days old. 

Thank you! :-)