# How to define the minimum length of array of objects in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have my questionsModel.js as such

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Question Required'],
      trim: true
  },
  options: [  // this array should atleast have two objects meaning two options
    {
        optionNo: Number,
        optionValue:{
            type: String,
            required: [true,'Option required'],
            trim: true
        }
    },
  ]
});

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;
```

I want to have minimum two options for each question how do I implement this in the "options" field above.

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Question Required'],
      trim: true
  },
  options: {
    type: [{
        optionNo: Number,
        optionValue:{
            type: String,
            required: [true,'Option required'],
            trim: true
        }
    }],
    validate: [(val) -> val.length > 1, 'Must have minimum two options']
  }
});
```

Solution 2

```
questionSchema.path('options')
    .validate((val) -> val.length > 1, 'Must have minimum two options');
```

Reference

[SchemaType.prototype.validate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate)

[Array size in Mongoose schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514790/how-to-set-limit-for-array-size-in-mongoose-schema)